# Scala nested parametrized class

Tags: scala, generics, types

In my scala app I have two abstract classes:

```
abstract class Definition
abstract class Evaluator[T <: Definition]
```

I also have some definitions and corresponding evaluators. What I'm trying to create is class that would look like this:

```
abstract class AbstractEvaluationContext[E <: Evaluator[D]]
```

with some methods.

My question is: how can I access the type of definition that is to be evaluated by the evaluator. eg. with class:

```
class SomeEvaluationContext extends AbstractEvaluationContext[SomeEvaluator[SomeDefinition]]
```

how can I get the type SomeDefinition in my AbstractEvaluationContext class?

For example I would like to define a method:

```
def getDefinition(): D = ...
```

which return type would be the definition passed as evaluator parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your class this way:

```
abstract class AbstractEvaluationContext[D <: Definition, E <: Evaluator[D]] {
  def getDefinition(): D
}

class SomeEvaluationContext extends
  AbstractEvaluationContext[SomeDefinition, SomeEvaluator[SomeDefinition]] {
  def getDefinition(): SomeDefinition = ???
}
```

Actually your code in question is invalid. There is no declaration of type `D`:

```
scala> abstract class AbstractEvaluationContext[E <: Evaluator[D]]
<console>:9: error: not found: type D
       abstract class AbstractEvaluationContext[E <: Evaluator[D]]
                                                               ^
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any way to avoid passing Definition type twice? Instead of [SomeDefinition, SomeEvaluator[SomeDefinition]] I'd prefer to write [SomeEvaluator[SomeDefinition]] since SomeDefinition is already included as SomeEvaluator parameter.

Comment: @gysyky: No, you have to specify both type parameters.